# Font-independent custom symbols

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I was interested in using a custom symbol.  So, I played around with some numbers in a MWE (because it was much faster to compile) before trying it out in my original document.  I wound up with the following.  (The parameters were just found by experimentation.)

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mkern -3mu \in \mkern -16mu \makebox[0.5em]{\raisebox{-.225em}{\scalebox{1.68}[1]{\_}}}}}

\begin{document}

$x\ineq y$

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Then, I added this to the document I wanted to actually use it in, but it didn't quite look so nice.  Below, I've included the same MWE as before, but now with most font-related commands that appear in the preamble of the document intended for final use.  <s>(These lines were inserted between `\documentclass{minimal}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`.)</s>

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{avant}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mkern -3mu \in \mkern -16mu \makebox[0.5em]{\raisebox{-.225em}{\scalebox{1.68}[1]{\_}}}}}

\begin{document}

$x\ineq y$

\end{document}
```

[image: Final]

Now, I could just redefine the symbol with parameters modified so that things look right with this new preamble, but this solution is less than ideal because, every time I want to reuse the symbol in a different setup, I will have to go back and play with the numbers again.  It would be best if I could define a single command that was robust enough to display 'correctly' in almost any environment.  Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Never use `minimal` to begin with. And `mathptmx` is not the best math font package: it's essentially a 20th century hack for getting an almost decent Times-like font with math support.

Comment: You could measure the width of the character. What does this have to do with `mathptmx`? Somewhat confused. But please provide complete code we can compile and do not use `minimal`.

Comment: What's actually wrong with minimal?  I've been using this in most of my MWEs because my understanding was that it just simply loaded less LaTeX macros, which meant less overhead.

Comment: @cfr The complete code you can compile is obtained by taking the first complete MWE and inserting the second group of lines between the aforementioned two lines.  I figured saying this would be better than just repeating code, but I will edit the question to just contain the complete code samples in both cases.

Comment: @cfr Try adding/deleting only that line.  I found that the output changed.

Comment: There's a question explaining why not to use `minimal`.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Answer (score 2):

Font independence is a dream, I'm afraid.

You can try underlining, but pretending the `\in` is slightly thinner than its bounding box. The amount of “thinning” depends on the font, but it's not difficult to adapt the macro to the current needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\ineq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mspace{1.2mu}%
    \underline{\mspace{-1.2mu}\in\mspace{-1.2mu}}%
    \mspace{1.2mu}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$x\ineq y$

\end{document}
```

**Notes**

1. `minimal` should never be used
2. `mathptmx` is a 20 year old hack for getting a math font that could almost decently accompany Times as text font
3. Nowadays, NewTX does a much better job.

[image]

Comment: Why is it that `minimal` should never be used?

Comment: @JonathanGleason See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Answer (score 1):

Three versions shown below, by uncommenting the appropriate lines in the MWE.  I relied on the fact that a minus sign should generally be a similar width to  `\in` (actually I shrink the minus to 0.85 times its original width).  I used `stackengine` for the sub-placement of the minus, and `scalerel` to make it work across math styles.

As egreg notes, it is hard to get a universal definition across fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine,scalerel}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-1.5\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\in}{%
    \SavedStyle\kern.5\LMpt\hstretch{.85}{-}}{U}{c}{F}{T}{S}}}}}

\begin{document}

$x\ineq y \quad\scriptstyle x\ineq y \quad\scriptscriptstyle x\ineq y$

\end{document}
```

Computer Modern:

[image]

`mathptmx`

[image]

`newtxmath`

[image]