# Custom symbol (general techniques for a MWE -at least-)

Tags: symbols

**New Question:**

> After the comment of @marmot and my closer look at the related post he proposed (twice) [sorry for this!] I realized that the request of my question was really close to the request of [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480768/how-do-you-make-your-own-symbol-when-detexify-fails)  mentioned.The difference is that I don't talk at all about [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) that could fail for many reasons (like if can't recognize separate curves and see them as one or the opposite etc) thus I would not use it in the title of this question. But this doesn't make my question a non-duplicate of that. I will turn my question to a meta-question with the next request (that was one of the main ideas before but the only idea that separates this question of the linked above) that makes the question a meta-post as @JouleV instantly felt.

Many questions that are looking for specific symbols are closed (and fairly in the most of the cases) as a duplicate of the question [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/120578). But sometimes the answers there doesn't help because the symbol doesn't exist in these resources or because a similar but not close enough symbol can be found there. Like in creating graphics here at TeX.SX, we could or could not ask for a MWE in such cases and this post is supposed to help in this direction (of creating a MWE of the requested custom symbol). Of course if the user that asks for the symbol had for example an extended experience/knowledge on `tikz` (foe example) would possibly not even ask. But in many cases, (s)he could use some basic skills/techniques/resources available in this (community wiki) CW post to create at least a basic MWE (if can't really get to close enough to the requested symbol).

**My request is:**

I am asking for some **basic techniques/resources and skills** with such **an explanation (if possible)** that a user who comes here looking for a custom symbol could use them to create at least a [MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480768/how-do-you-make-your-own-symbol-when-detexify-fails) showing where could go with these techniques.

PS: This question (for example) could have  an answer using `tikz` but without advanced commands in order to be usable for the purpose of helping people that have no `tikz` knowledge but could be open to learn to draw a straight or a curved line in order to try, and ask if they will not succeed on this.

PS2: I have in mind that TeX.SX is not an online courses site and that if I am asking for such a basic Custom Symbols "courses" someone could ask some basic `tikz` knowledge (at least for a MWE too) and this could go on. So, is you feel that the question is not appropriate (even as it is here -after this edit-) neither for here nor for meta... feel free to vote to close. I still feel that could help through the links added even as closed as a duplicate.

---

**Old Question:**

> This question is something I didn't find on TeX.SX questions but I found many answers instead specific to the symbol required. I am opening this question and I have in mind that it should become a Community Wiki (CW) where users that asking for specific symbols not available via `[Xe/Lua(La)]TeX` or via fonts and packages, could get an advice though the answers of this "discussion/post" (No answer will be accepted and every answer is supposed to propose a specific technique) or through combinations of these answers. The user that looks for a custom symbol could also create his/her MWE about the requested symbol using one or more of these answers (if the approach of this creation is related to `TeX` and friends -because answers with `metafont` software could be also acceptable for me-).

Related posts are:

1. [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/120578) 
   where the user that is looking for a specific symbol should look before asking for a custom created version (of course he could use this post alternative to create his own custom version, but in my opinion a question on customizing already available symbols should provide a respectful reason for this and this customization should be avoided if there is not a real need for it.)
2. [Creating custom mathematical symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/413073/120578) and many similar questions BUT it asks for a specific symbol and doesn't ask about the techniques on creating this symbol. Also it is specific to tikz and not to any other approach.
3. [Overlay symbol with another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12895/120578) or [Font-independent custom symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361317/font-independent-custom-symbols)that are also useful in many cases but are specific to overlay or underline an existing symbol and can be used only in specific symbol creations. (Of course the answer or even the code of their question would be a useful answer here in many cases)
4. [Create a symbol font from SVG symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22487/120578) that I have no experience to talk about, but sure could be one of the techniques and I suppose that a copy paste of the answers would not be acceptable here but a link to that answer at a list here that could be visible with a short description could be nice.
5. [Creating a custom math symbol from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148366/120578) that is also too specific for the symbol but an answer describing the technique would be a nice answer
6. [How to use a custom, scalable, symbol in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex) is also relative as @ StevenB.Segletes mentioned in his comment (thanks)

> 7. [How do you make your own symbol when Detexify fails?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480768/how-do-you-make-your-own-symbol-when-detexify-fails) that @marmot had mentioned to me before and now (and I accidentally closed that open tab -of reference-) is really closed related and at the
>      moment I am writing this lines I feel that my question could possibly
>      be a duplicate of that. Feel free to vote for close, but I still think (as anyone confident about the formulation of his thoughts) that this wording in this question makes more clear the request... Anyway I am not sure now if it should stay open and become a CW or if it should be closed as a duplicate of this last one and of course I don't believe that a better wording (in the eyes of its author :P) should keep a duplicate of a question open. Not sure yet...

If the community thinks for such a question is not appropriate for this site (or that it could cause troubles in any case), it can be closed. But I think that it will be really useful and that could be a reference point as a CW for people looking for symbols not available otherwise.

PS1: Of course the answers could include specific symbols, but some basic explanation on the technique while creating them would be more useful than just adding the code for this specific symbol.

PS2: My answer would be an answer of someone with very basic knowledge of the `tikz` package usage, and I could post it mostly to help people that would like to create their custom symbol in order to be able to create their [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) without enough `tikz` knowledge. (But I will add it tomorrow -if this question is finally acceptable and not such an answer is already posted here-) due to work I have to do (about it but about other things too) today.

PS3: I am not sure if this question breaks the rules of the general TeX.SX! philosophy, because it is not about a specific symbol but about possible techniques that could used in many cases. I am sure that here are people with aadmirable `tikz` knowledge and I would ask from them (if they post an answer) to include in their post as less commands/options/tikz features as possible in order to be an answer that could help a user that couldn't already create this symbol by him(/her)self using such advanced knowledge (It is just an idea -- feel free to not respect it.).

Comment: Hmm, this question should be in meta IMHO :)

Comment: @JouleV ... The question about opening this question could be in meta... because if this question would be in meta, also almost all that asking about symbols should be in meta too (see for example the No 1. linked).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex

Comment: Even much closer related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799

Comment: @marmot, I didn't pay enough attention to the question itself (now I think that the picture inside the questions was not such a good addition -without it better answers and more techniques would be there possibly-). The problem there is that the answers are not enough (in amount and quality*) to be usable from people that would like to create a symbol or at least their MWE while asking for a custom symbol. Thinking of rephrasing my post to turn it to a specific meta-question for people that would like to create a custom symbol and are open to try creating a MWE (tikz could be nice option).

Comment: This could be interesting, but too broad, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg ... you are right... I am not sure too,  but if it was a meta-discussion post that no answer will be the accepted one, may be could not be too broad since anyone could of course propose a different technique but the technique should just give basic concepts like mixing or stacking characters, drawing/filling curves and straight lines, customizing a font character... All these different techniques could be add in a list categorized in the body of the questions and could just offer the really basic skills (just lines and curves for example in tikz answer).